# Correspondence between submodules and quotient modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

What is the (natural) bijection between the set of all sub modules upto isomorphism and set of all isomorphic quotient modules upto isomorphism of a finitely generated torsion module over a PID. Is there any inclusion relation between these classes?

Comment: What is «the isomorphic class of sub modules»

Comment: collection of all sub modules upto isomorphism of modules

Comment: So, the «set of isomorphism classes of submodules».

Comment: This (or half of this) was essentially asked for abelian groups [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/is-every-quotient-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-isomorphic-to-some-subgroup-of) and for PIDs the reasoning is just the same. The conclusion there is that every quotient of an finite abelian group is isomorphic to a subgroup.

Comment: yes. this is what I mean exactly.

Comment: Well, then edit the question so that it is clearly expressed :-)

Comment: On the other hand, if there is a sensible bijection between the sets of isomorphism classes of quotients and of submodules, there iss exactly *one* such bijection, so *naturality* does not mean much in this context!

Comment: ya. but I am looking for a bijection which is natural.

Comment: I dont understand your statement clearly. please explain me

Comment: Natural in what sense?

Comment: I think it is better for you to read the related question I linked to, think a bit about it, and then try to solve your problem.

Comment: For abilion groups (Z-modules) I have understand the answer. but how to prove for general free torsion module over a PID? thanks.

Comment: natural in the sense given a sub module we can able to guess the corresponding quotient module. there should be some natural relation between them. I cant able to tell clearly. sorry.

Comment: Well, you apparently can do this for abelian groups: what is the correspondence in that case?

Answer (score 4):

If $M$ is a f.g. torsion module over a PID $R$, one can show that every submodule of $M$ is isomorphic to a quotient of module of $M$, and vice versa, by looking at a decomposition of $M$ into direct summands of cyclic modules. However, this correspondence is not natural.

However, the following works: Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$. Then $\hom(-,K/R)$ ("Pontrjagin dual") is a contravariant functor from $R$-modules to $R$-modules. For every $R$-module $M$ there is a canonical homomorphism $M \to \hom(\hom(M,K/R),K/R)$. If $M$ is finite cyclic, this is easily seen to be an isomorphism. Hence, it is an isomorphism for all f.g. torsion modules. It follows that $\hom(-,K/R)$ is an anti-equivalence of categories from f.g. torsion modules to itsself.

Now it follows by abstract nonsense that submodules (quotients) of $M$ correspond naturally to quotients (submodules) of $\hom(M,K/R)$.

Besides, for every f.g. torsion module $M$ there is *some* isomorphism $M \cong \hom(M,K/R)$ (which is not natural). But once this is fixed, we get a correspondence between submodules of $M$ and quotients of $M$, where these modules are abstractly isomorphic.

Comment: what is $K/R$? is it quotient ring? thanks.

Comment: It's a quotient module.