# Natural maps between quotient modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and $N'\subseteq N\subseteq M$ be two submodules. Is there a natural way to consider the module $M/N$ as a submodule of $M/N'$?

I saw sometimes in the proof, that for example $R$ is a ring, $p$ is an element. We can get an exact sequence (e.g., $\mathbb Z$ and a prime number $p$)
$$0\to R/(p)\to R/(p)^n\to R/(p)^{n-1}\to0.$$
But the first map is not very natural for me.

Comment: These two things are unconnected. The maps you're looking at in the second bit are almost certainly multiplication by $p^{n-1}$ and reduction modulo $p^{n-1}$, respectively. Try it with $R=\Bbb Z$, for instance.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you that is very clear now. So in general, my first claim makes no sense?

Comment: Not an answer, but surely relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364123/correspondence-between-submodules-and-quotient-modules

Comment: The simplest counterexample would be a module $M$ with a unique composition series $M\geqslant N\geqslant 0$ with $M/N\not\simeq N$. (Which doesn't seem to happen in the well-behaved modules I know, alas.)

Comment: $\{0\}\subseteq 2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.  However $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ does not in include in $\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think $0 \to \mathbb R \to \mathbb R[x] / (x^2 + 1)(x - 1) \to \mathbb R[x] / (x^2 + 1) \to 0$, considered as a sequence of $\mathbb R[x]$-modules, should work. All three modules have different $\mathbb R$-dimension, so they cannot be isomorphic as modules.