# Does $G$ always have a subgroup isomorphic to $G/N$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Must $G$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $G/N$? My first guess is no, but by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups it is true for finite abelian groups, so finding a counterexample has been a little tough. The finite case is also interesting for me.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z$ is a finitely generated abelian group, and has no subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a finite counterexample, take a look at the [subgroup structure of the quaternions](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_quaternion_group), a nonabelian group of order $8$.

By inspection, it's straightforward to verify that $Q/Z(Q)\simeq V_4$, the Klein group. However, the only subgroups of $Q$ of order $4$ are $\langle i\rangle\simeq\langle j\rangle\simeq\langle k\rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}/(4)$. So $Q$ does not have a subgroup isomorphic to $Q/Z(Q)$.

Comment: thank you, am I correct that there can't be a finite abelian counterexample?

Comment: @JorgeFernández Yes, take a look at this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/is-every-quotient-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-isomorphic-to-some-subgroup-of).

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be the reals $\mathbb{R}$under addition. Let $N$ be the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition. $G/N$ is the group of reals modulo $1$. This has a non-zero element whose square is $1$, the equivalence class of $0.5$. So $G/N$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $G$.

Comment: nice, thanks, I would also like an example in finite groups though

Comment: hmm, sorry if I'm coming off as a major noob, but doesn't the fundamental theorem of abelian groups imply any finite examples must be non-abelian?

Comment: Haha, sorry Dan, I'm not really sure what I should do, should I find a quotient which gives me an element of order smaller than I could find in the group?