# Properties of finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> > Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ . Then choose the correct statement.

a)  If d divides n, then there exist a subgroup of $G$ of order $d$

b) If d divides n, then there exist an element of $G$ of order $d$

c) If every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic then $G$ is cyclic.

d)  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then there exist a subgroup $N$ such that $\frac{G}{N} \cong H$.

for a) I know that the converse of the Lagrange's Theorem for abelian group is true.

for b) and d) Take $G = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 $  has no element of order 4.

for c)  take $G= \mathbb Z_2 \times Z_2$ , every subgroup of $G$ is cyclic but $G$ is not cyclic .

I would be thankful if someone checks my solution.

Comment: For (d) I have some doubts.

Comment: $G= \mathbb Z_2 \times  \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$,  Is $G$ has a subgroup of order 4

Comment: How does your example help you for d)?

Comment: @almagest :  Since $G$ has a subgroup of order 2 which i  have taken as counter example, if $G$ has no subgroup of order 4.,  we get a ccounter examlple for d),  I am not sure about d),  i am trying to find a counnter example.

Comment: @ egreg : what will you say about d)

Comment: d) looks true to me.

Comment: d) looks true to me, too. Anyway, your example is not a counterexample to d), because every subgroup and every factor group of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$ for some $0\leq r\leq 4$, and every $r$ occurs.

Comment: For solution to (d), see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/is-every-quotient-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-isomorphic-to-some-subgroup-of).

Comment: @GeorgeLaw That is not the same property as (d).