# If G is a finite Abelian group, and H is a subgroup of G, How can I prove that G/H is isomorphic to another subgroup N of G?.

Tags: group-theory

If G is an abelian finite group, and H is a subgroup of G, How can I prove that G/H is isomorphic to another subgroup N of G?.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you show us what you've tried so far, or what's your thoughts about the problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is false for example when $G$ is cyclic of order $4$ and $|H|=2$.

Comment: @Derek  What was the duplicate you considered?  It can be added (edited) into the "pink" banner as such.

Comment: @DerekHolt No, it's true. The question doesn't ask for $N\cap H=\{0\}$

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @egreg It asks for "another subgroup", which means a subgroup other than $H$. The word "another" means different from the original.

Comment: @DerekHolt Disputable. Anyway there's no mention about splitting.

Comment: See [subgroups of finite abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837011/subgroups-of-finite-abelian-groups/1837047) for references.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write abelian groups additively.

You can use the character group: if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then its character group is $\hat{G}=\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.

From the structure theorem of abelian groups, it follows that $G$ is the direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups. If $C$ is a finite cyclic $p$-group, then $\hat{C}\cong C$, hence there is a (non canonical) isomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to\hat{G}$.

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, consider $H'=\varphi(H)$, so $\hat{G}/H'\cong G/H$. Now prove that, defining
$$
N=\{x\in G:\chi(x)=0,\text{ for all }\chi\in H'\},
$$
you have $N\cong \hat{G}/H'$.

Comment: Really doubtful that the OP has encountered the material necessary to understand your answer.

Comment: How would you prove it?

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

Because $G$ is abelian, every subgroup will be normal. Therefore, it makes sense to consider $G/H$ for a subgroup $H$.

Then, use the first isomorphism theorem such that $H = ker(f)$