# Prove that this abelian group has a subgroup isomorphic to G/H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I had tried some assignments earlier but couldn't ask questions here then due to being ill so, I am asking now. I have done a  masters level course in group theory.

> If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite abelian group $G$, then $G$ has a subgroup that is isomorphic to $G / H$.

Order of subgroup always divides order of group. Let $|H|=m$ and $|G| =n$. Now there also exists a group of order $n/m$ as $n/m$ divides $n$ and as in abelian groups if $x \mid |G|$ then there always exists a subgroup  of order $x$. So, there exists a group of order $|G/H|.$

But How can I  prove that it is isomorphic to $G/H$?

I have read theory of finitely generated Abelian Groups but I am at loss of ideas.

Comment: Hint: Use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788598/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-then-g-has-a-subgroup-that